# Multiple charts in separate divs, single range and zoom picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a simple dashboard with six div's each containing a highstocks chart. Each of them currently has a zoom picker (1m, 3m, 6m, YTD etc.) and a range picker below it.

1. Is it possible to have a single, separate range and zoom picker that will affect all charts?
2. Is it possible to synchronise zoom/range across all charts? I.e. keep the zoom/range pickers on each chart but once one is changed, all other ones are changed too.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There is callback [`afterSetExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) and method [`setExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes) - now just synchronize charts.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible,

It is achievable with highcharts itself. Render navigator chart and other charts in different divs. There is an example given here in highcharts demos called [master-detail](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) chart for your ref.

you an have your own date range selector and apply the selected dates using the [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) method.

In this way you can have a look and feel near to a highstock while using highcharts. But the total number of points per chart may effect the performance.

--EDIT--
you can do that with highstocks as well use afterSetExtremes method and manually set the extremes of all other charts when the extremes of one chart(the one with navigator and rangeSelctor) is changed.

Comment: So it's not possible using highstocks?

Comment: See my comment above.. Anyway, who down-votes without saying why answer is wrong? It's irresponsible..

Comment: An upvote, because this is the correct way to have one rangeSelector affect multiple charts!